# can't recompile linux kernel after enabling lockdep

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

I am running linux within a UTM virtual machine on MacOS, with M1-pro processor.

I successfully enabled lockdep kernel hacking functionalities by running `make menuconfig` from within `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0.72`.

However, when I try to recompile the kernel by running `sudo make ARCH=arm -j4` I keep getting the following error message:

No rule to make target '/arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl' needed by '/arch/arm/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd-oabi.h'

I also tried running `sudo make ARCH=arm64 -j4`, but then I get an error from missing `classmap.h`

I also tried with kernel version `0.69`, the outcome is the same.

Anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: As you could guess, `/usr/src/linux-headers-...` contains only **headers** of the Linux kernel. These headers could be used for build a module against the running kernel. But those headers are insufficient for rebuild the entire kernel. You need full **sources** of the kernel. Just google how to obtain sources for a Linux distribution you are using.

Comment: Thanks! I also tried re-downloading the entire source folder, but then I should recompile the kernel from in there?